# Image resize library for Node.js site on Heroku hosting

Tags: node.js

Could you suggest some node js library for resizing images which will be compatible with Heroku hosting (Linux), please?

We used this, but it didn't work on Heroku.
https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I just tested - the latest gm works on Heroku via its imagemagick subclass. Aaron is tha man :)

```
imageMagick = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/canvas-heroku

Additionally, if Heroku supports GD, take a look at this one as well:

https://npmjs.org/package/node-gd

https://github.com/taggon/node-gd

Alternatively, if it supports ImageMagick:

https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

Comment: Thanks, but seems node-gd not working for Linux hosting, too (as ImageMagick).

Comment: Not yet, but I am going to try it. Thanks.